# Alexa Skill is currently disabled in development stage when Simulate from Ask CLI [Alexa SDK in NodeJS]

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-sdk-nodejs

I have created new Skill using Ask CLI. 
And deploy both skill & lambda function.
Now I was trying to test skill using ask simulate CLI command but got an error message that **Skill is currently disabled in the development stage. Please enable skill in order to call this API.**

However, I was still able to test it in Alexa Skill Console (web)
I was used below command for testing.

`ask simulate --skill-id amzn1.ask.skill.bc889dcf-fc17-4a64-bbb3-077f6a4f5e39 --text "my newcls
skill" --locale en-US`

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the skill?

Check your Alexa app for the list of installed skills to see if it is there. I don't think that creating a skill automatically installs it.

You may even need to reinstall it if a 'live' version was previously installed.

Comment: I have checked in alexa.amazon.com it contains new skill that I have created. if it was not available then I should not able to test it from Skill kit too.